# Convert string using regex expression

Tags: sql, regex

I convert it using substring and it working fine but I have to convert lots of the and it will take time.

I was told regex is much more efficient and faster.

Any advice on regex ?

converting string1 to string2 using regex

```
string1 = '96457fa012456c41bf9200011da2d8fa'

string2='\96\45\7f\a0\12\45\6c\41\bf\92\00\01\1d\a2\d8\fa'
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You want to add backslashes before every pair of characters? Which language or RDBMS are you doing this in?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: hi steve, I am doing it in SQL stored procedure

Comment: @user2150394, what RDBMS (kind of SQL database, such as MySQL, SQL Server, etc.)? Not all databases even have regular expressions.

Comment: Do you need this to be regx? A different method without loop?

Answer (score 1):

This works in Oracle - replacing Oracle's regex implementation with SQL Server's should be straightforward:

```
select regexp_replace(
  '96457fa012456c41bf9200011da2d8fa', 
  '(..)', 
  '\\\1') 
from dual
```

Explanation:

- we want to match any pair of characters =>  ".."
- we want to "store" the characters we just matched, therefore enclose them in a capturing group => "(..)"
- in our replacement string, we want to get the contents of our matching group => "\1"
- and we want to add a backslash before each group => "\\\1"
- dual is just a dummy table in Oracle

Comment: From the example in the question, it looks like the backslash should be added before the group, not after. `'\\\1'`, I would guess.

Comment: Hi, me again with another nitpick. :-p `'\\1'` appears to escape the backslash, yielding a literal `\` and literal `1` rather than a backreference. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/8804

Comment: @Wiseguy: You mean a literal ``\``. `\`\\`` appears to escape the `\``

Comment: @Eric Yes, sorry, I overlooked my mistake and had stepped away. I meant the result was a literal "\" and a literal "1".

Comment: Argl. That's what happens if you post something without testing it first. I've added the backslash needed for escaping - thanks @Wiseguy